# Why isn't the javascript console.log the same as my .innerHTML response

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, coldfusion, cfml

I have an issue with my ajax response format. My javascript receives data from a CFM query and it should be stored as a JSON response, it looks correct with I print my response on to a div/header/paragraph... etc however when I console.log my response it prints a jumbled garage. Looking for help to store the response as a parable json variable.

JavaScipt Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getFilteredYear() {
    var year = document.getElementById("yearList").value
    var postData = {
      year: year
        };
    var ajaxResponse = $.ajax({
      type: "post",
            url: "http://localhost:8888/New/api.cfm",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify( postData ),
          success : function(response){
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = response;
        console.log(response);
      
         }
     });
  }
</script>
```

Cold Fusion Code: Api.cfm

```
<cfset requestBody = toString( getHttpRequestData().content ) />

<cfif isJSON( requestBody )>
    <cfset var ="#deserializeJSON( requestBody )#">
    <cfset year = var.year>


    <cfquery name="qList" datasource="aws_db">
    SELECT * FROM Continuous_Home_Care WHERE Continuous_Home_Care.Year = #var.year#
    </cfquery>  



    <!--- Echo back POST data. --->
<cfdump var="#serializeJSON(qList)#" />

</cfif>
```

Outputs:

[image: When printed into a div:]Console.log output:

Console.log():

```
<!-- ==start== dump {ts '2022-11-08 18:13:28'} format: html -->
<div id="x3j" class="-lucee-dump"><style>
.-lucee-dump .disp-none { display: none; }
</style>
<script>
window.__Lucee = { initialized : false,
                addEventListeners : function(selector, event, handler, useCapture){
                    useCapture = useCapture || false;
                    Array.prototype.forEach.call(
                         document.querySelectorAll(selector)
                        ,function(el, ix) {
                          el.addEventListener(event, handler, useCapture);
                        }
                    );
                }
                ,getNextSiblings   : function(el){
                    var  orig = el
                        ,result = [];
                    while (el && el.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        if (el !== orig)
                            result.push(el);
                        el = el.nextElementSibling || el.nextSibling;
                    }
                    return result;
                }
                ,onDocumentReady           : function(){
                    var L = window.__Lucee;
                    if (L.initialized)
                        return;
                    L.addEventListeners(".collapse-trigger", "click", function(evt){
                        var tr = evt.target.closest("tr");
                        var siblings = L.getNextSiblings(tr);
                        siblings.forEach(function(el, ix){
                            el.classList.toggle("disp-none");
                        });
                    });
                    L.initialized = true;
                }
            }
            
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", __Lucee.onDocumentReady);
</script>
<style type="text/css">
div#x3j table {font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; empty-cells:show; color:#000; border-collapse:collapse;}
div#x3j td {border:1px solid #000; vertical-align:top; padding:2px; empty-cells:show;}
div#x3j td span {font-weight:bold;}
div#x3j td.luceeN0 {color:#990000;border-color:#990000;background-color:#fc9;}
div#x3j td.luceeH0 {color:#990000;border-color:#990000;background-color:#f60;}
</style>
<table title="/Users/xxxxx/Lucee/webapps/ROOT/New/api.cfm:15"><tr><td class="luceeH0">string</td><td class="luceeN0">{&quot;COLUMNS&quot;:[&quot;ID&quot;,&quot;Home&quot;,&quot;Assisted Living Facility&quot;,&quot;LTC/NF&quot;,&quot;Skilled Nursing Facility (SNF)&quot;,&quot;Inpatient Hospital&quot;,&quot;Inpatient Hospice Facility&quot;,&quot;Long Term Care Hospital&quot;,&quot;Inpatient Psychiatric Facility&quot;,&quot;Place Not Otherwise Specified&quot;,&quot;Hospice Home Care Provided in Hospice Facility&quot;,&quot;Year&quot;],&quot;DATA&quot;:[[6,150133149.00,46885968.00,19490091.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,452709.00,255456.00,2020]]}</td></tr></table></div>
<!-- ==stop== dump -->
```

Comment: Try returning one column from the result of the `qList` query and nothing else. (or a `valuelist()`, if you need to.) Right now you're dumping the ENTIRE thing as a struct - that includes all the styling that is native to CFML/Lucee. So it renders in HTML on the page, but it is nonsensical in javascript.

Comment: Try:
<cfoutput>#serializeJSON(qList)#</cfoutput>

Comment: There are several things missing or incorrect. First, dumping with cfdump is not the correct way of sending/output raw json to the browser. If you want to send html through json, you need to wrap that html into a variable and send that as @will belden said. Second: you need to set headers accordingly to set that content as json. Third: please use cfqueyparam in your SQL, because that code is vulnerable to sql injection as soon as it get public.

Answer (score 0):

> Why isn't the javascript console.log the same as my .innerHTML response

It *is* the same.

Your response is HTML. The browser is rendering HTML (that's what browsers do). The console is logging the raw HTML text you gave it, which is what *it* does.

What were you actually expecting to see in the log? Rendered HTML? No. The console is not a browser, it's a logger.

To prove this to yourself: save the contents of the log entry as `test.html`, and open it in a browser. You will see this:

[image]

Which is the same as the dump you included in your question!

So I think you don't actually have a problem here; just some expectations-management.

---

That said, there's an issue with your approach, you say this:

```
<!--- Echo back POST data. --->
<cfdump var="#serializeJSON(qList)#" />
```

That is not what that code is doing. That is using `<cfdump>` - a debugging tool and should not be in production code - to render data in a nice visual table for debug analysis.

You want to be returning your JSON to the browser. Depending on the rest of your method that you're not showing us, that's either:

```
<cfreturn qList>
```

Or:

```
<cfreturn serializeJson(qList)>
```

All you are currently doing is outputing some HTML. You want to *return* the data.